# Using post method in javascript

Tags: post, textarea

I would like to send text inside textarea to php using post method. I created a button, and I can extract the text from the textarea into a variable.

How can I pass the variable to php using POST and NOT using ajax or other libraries? Is there a simple way?

If not, how does ajax do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use javascript? If you don't want AJAX, then why not just use a standard HTML form submission? You can setup everything using javascript to build the HTML form and the browser will do the submission for you?

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

If it must be javascript, then it might be simplest to use JQuery to make an AJAX call.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: Basically my question is: If AJAX/JQuery can do it, how do they POST? I cannot find a javascript call to POST.

Comment: Added links to build an HTML form, and to use JQuery.